# Not able to connect to jmx metric running on HDP sandbox using jconsole

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hortonworks-sandbox

I added following properties to hbase-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.coprocessor.regionserver.classes</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.JMXListener</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>regionserver.rmi.registry.port</name>
  <value>61130</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>regionserver.rmi.connector.port</name>
  <value>61140</value>
</property>
```

Added following config to `hbase-env`:

```
export HBASE_JMX_BASE="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS="$HBASE_MASTER_OPTS $HBASE_JMX_BASE -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10101"  
export HBASE_REGIONSERVER_OPTS="$HBASE_REGIONSERVER_OPTS $HBASE_JMX_BASE -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10102"
```

Not able to access hbase jmx metric from jconsole remotely.